# How to understand an example of book java concurrency in practice?

Tags: java, concurrency, assertions, java-threads

> Listing 3.15. Class at Risk of Failure if Not Properly Published.

```
public class Holder {
 private int n;
 public Holder(int n) { this.n = n; }
 public void assertSanity() {
 if (n != n)
 throw new AssertionError("This statement is false.");
 }
}
```

My first question is why javac not optimize `if (n != n)`?

The following is my demo for the example

```
public class TestSync {
    private int n;

    public TestSync(int n) {
        this.n = n;
    }

    public void assertSanity() {
        if(n!=n)
            throw new AssertionError("This statement is false");
    }

    private static TestSync test;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                while(true) {
                    if(test == null) test = new TestSync(2);
                    else test = null;
                }
            }
        }).start();

        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                while(true) {
                    if(test != null)
                        try {
                            test.assertSanity();
                        } catch (NullPointerException e) {

                        }
                }
            }
        }).start();
    }
}
```

And my second question is Did I do the right thing? Because it occurs no exception when I run the demo.

**UPDATE**

1.Addition to my first question:
`javap -c TestSync.class`

```
public void assertSanity();
    Code:
       0: aload_0
       1: getfield      #3                  // Field n:I
       4: aload_0
       5: getfield      #3                  // Field n:I
       8: if_icmpeq     21
      11: new           #4                  // class java/lang/AssertionError
      14: dup
      15: ldc           #5                  // String This statement is false
      17: invokespecial #6                  // Method java/lang/AssertionError."<init>":(Ljava/lang/Object;)V
      20: athrow
      21: return
```

I thinked javac would optimize `if(n!=n)` to `if(false)` and shrink it.

2.Why I still add `try{}catch(NullPointerException e)` after `if(test != null)`?

Because I think field `test` may be setted `null` by the other thread after `if(test!=null)`.

Comment: What's the question? How do you know javac isn't optimizing that? Why is there a try catch for a NullPointerException inside an if statement for the null object?

Comment: @cricket_007 already update my question

Comment: I could be wrong, but should `test` be `synchronized`?

Comment: @cricket_007 yes, but I want to make the example throw AssertionError exception as supposed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, `javac` almost never optimizes the code, you’re compiling. Only when the values are *compile-time constants*, `javac` is required to evaluate expressions at compile-time, which itself form compile-time constants, see [JLS §15.28. Constant Expressions](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.28).

However, operations get optimized at runtime and it is even the absence of thread synchronization measures that allows the optimizer to use optimistic assumptions, like that a variable won’t change between two reads. So the `n!=n` expression starts with a low likelihood of ever evaluate to `true` due to the short time between the reads¹ and will almost never be `true` after the optimizer kicked in. So while the expression `n!=n` is not guaranteed to be always `false`, it’s unlikely to ever encounter it to be `true` in practice.

Of course, according to Murphy’s Law, it will never happen when you try to provoke that error anyway, but once in a while at the customer, but never reproducible…

¹ Note that even if the second thread reads the initial `0` value due to the race condition, `n!=n` will only fail, if does not read the initial `0` again in the subsequent read.

Comment: **So the n!=n expression starts with a low likelihood of ever evaluate to false**
I think `false` should be `true`

Comment: You’re right. The `n!=n` is so unnatural, that it is easy to confuse.