# Will this AssertionError never be thrown in this case?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, visibility, safe-publication

First off the code, from JCIP listing http://jcip.net/listings/StuffIntoPublic.java and
http://jcip.net/listings/Holder.java

```
public class SafePublication {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
//        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName());
        StuffIntoPublic t = new StuffIntoPublic();
        t.initialize();
        while (true) {
            new Thread(() -> { t.holder.assertSanity(); }).start();
        }
    }
}

//@author Brian Goetz and Tim Peierls
class StuffIntoPublic {
    public Holder holder;

    public void initialize() {
//        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName());
        holder = new Holder(42);
    }
}

//@author Brian Goetz and Tim Peierls
class Holder {
    private int n;

    public Holder(int n ) {
        this.n = n;
    }

    public void assertSanity() {
        if (n != n) {
            throw new AssertionError("This statement is false.");
        }
    }
}
```

I am saying that the AssertionError will never be thrown in this case because of the Thread.start() happens before guarantee. Both of the System.out.printlns that are commented prints main, meaning that the main thread is which spawns all the later threads by making and calling start on the threads in the while(true) loop.

And since that is the thread that created and initialized Holder, all subsequent threads are safe to be a perfectly visible holder due to the happens-before guarantee. Am I right?

I even tried running this code for a really long time and no assertion errors.

However, if the main looked like below, then I believe it will be possible for an AssertionError

```
 public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName());
        StuffIntoPublic t = new StuffIntoPublic();
        new Thread(() -> t.initialize() ).start();
        while (true) {
            new Thread(() -> { t.holder.assertSanity(); }).start();
        }
    }
```

Comment: From where did you take `SafePublication` class code?

Comment: I wrote that code

Comment: Then I do not understand matter of your question

Comment: Actually, `SafePublication` isn't safe because `holder = new Holder(42);` is an unsafe publication.

Comment: In the main method of SafePublication, can an AssertionError be thrown?

Comment: @Andrew Sure, but if this was the only code that ever used holder, is it possible for that main method to throw an AssertionError?

Comment: @katiex7, no, new threads will see the `t.holder` **after** its proper initialisation.

Comment: Because of the happens before guarantee of thread start right?

Comment: Yes, you have a valid *happens-before* relationship when starting a thread after the initialization and never modifying the shared state. It should still mentioned that “tried running this code for a really long time and no assertion errors” is not a sufficient test, as even in the case of an improper publication, getting an `AssertionError` is *very* unlikely here, as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26714510/2711488)  and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40182163/2711488).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is safe, because `Thread#start` guarantees *happens-before*. To be more wordy: any read/write to any variable that happens before `Thread#start` (I tend to think *above* in program order if you want), will also happen *before* any action within that Thread (it's `run` method).

Indeed, that could happen to break and throw that error, if there were no happens before (to allow re-orderings) and if program execution would allow those potential re-orderings. I am even inclined to say *and* a proper CPU used with weak memory model (assuming you are on Intel, which is a strong memory model) could increase that chance, but I am not sure.

So, as far as I can tell, the actions would take place in the following order: first the the publishing the reference is re-ordered with variable `n` (there is no happens-before, so this is allowed). Thread1 creates an instance of `Holder`. Thread2 sees that published reference and calls that method. It reads the variable `n` to be `zero` (remember that re-ordering happened and `n` is not yet written, thus has a default value of `zero`), so it then does the `!=` check, *but* Thread1 that created `Holder`, writes `n` to be `12` for example *before* Thread2 reads it again (in the `!=n` part). So this can fail.

Making the value `final` would solve this as it introduces the right memory barriers, or *happens-before* rules.