# Reordering instruction

Tags: java, concurrency

I am aware of instruction reordering but in the following link 
[Will this AssertionError never be thrown in this case?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48138107/will-this-assertionerror-never-be-thrown-in-this-case)
In approved answer there is a line:

> first the the publishing the reference is re-ordered with variable n (there is no happens-before, so this is allowed). Thread1 creates an instance of Holder"

I could not understand the line. Could anyone explain this. How this reordering would happen. I am aware `thread.start()` has happen before relationship.

what i understand about reordering in java is that instructions can be reordered if they do not have happen before relationship.

```
int c=0;
int d=1;
```

can be reordered as

```
int d=1;
int c=0;
```

But user explained if `thread.starts()` would not have happen before relationship then publishing the reference might get reordered with variable n(It is allowed). I couldn't understand how. Reference is in other class and variable n is in different class.

Comment: I will take care of formatting further. Thanks

Comment: @Ivan Problem is that i am not able to imagine how code will look like after instruction reordering. I am assuming sequential instructions can be reordered. Can you post a snippet how it might get looked like after instruction reorder? That would help.

Answer (score 0):

It could happen if there is no happens-before and if reference to `t.holder` is set before `Holder` object is fully initialized. In this case we could have one thread executing

```
public Holder(int n ) {
    this.n = n;
}
```

And another one executing

```
if (n != n) {
        throw new AssertionError("This statement is false.");
}
```

Second thread reads value of `n` twice so if we are lucky (or unlucky) the first thread will execute assignment in constructor before those two reads and exception will be thrown.

Comment: This thing i have guessed. If it were not happens before. Then  before fully constructing object, your threads might have started accessing value of n in case of n!=n. In first access it might read value of n as 0 and in second access, it might be possible till that time object has been initialized and value of n has been set as 42. So error would be thrown out. So Over here what is mean by reordering over here?

Comment: Thanks. Now i understood.